# Static site authoring with Github Wiki (.md rendering from Git with custom CSS)?

Tags: markdown, wiki, github, static-site-generator

I am relatively happy with Github wiki for a bunch of projects, but would like to see the wiki content on mysite.com with a custom CSS (without the Github chrome).

There must be a tool that has pre-set settings for this (take a Git repository of markdown files + a baseurl, render static html) and a single command that would make it happen?

Comment: Is [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) what you need? It uses Jekyll. Or you can use [gitlab pages](https://gitlab.com/groups/pages) with many other static site generators.

Comment: No, I know Github pages and that is not it. I want to "export" Github Wiki content as a static site. Obviously this should not be that difficult task with some scripting, but I would expect that this could be a common task and there could be software with ready made settings for such scenario.

Probably something from https://github.com/gollum would help or https://github.com/chjj/marked, but I have yet to find a "oneliner" for exporting Github wiki that would work flawlessly with wikilinks etc.

Comment: Take a look at [mdwiki](http://www.mdwiki.info/).